# PHPBB 3.0.8 weird error

Tags: php, html, css, phpbb

No idea why it is repeating the template:

[Check out the error here](http://www.igl-esports.com/forums/)

It is a clean install of phpBB. The problem is not the style I have installed, the same problem occurs with the default prosilver style.

Comment: The same HTML is being output twice. There's `<!DOCTYPE html` .. `</html>` then some garbage `�����w�ep�jH$Xi���` .. and then the same HTML.

Comment: Yes I saw that, now any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Does the default prosilver theme look correct?

If so, you can check the index_body.html in the new theme you installed to see if it has more than one header/body/footer. If it does, it's probably the same way in all the templates.
If not, it could be another MOD you installed.

Looks like all your pages are showing more than one html output.

Comment: "The problem is not the style I have installed, the same problem occurs with the default prosilver style." -- I have no mods installed, its a clean install

Comment: Try purging the cache. See if that solves the problem.
(Click the purge cache button on the first page of the Administration control panel)

Comment: Do any other php pages on your site do that? or just phpBB?
You also may want to try deleting and reuploading a fresh copy of includes/functions.php and maybe common.php. I'm not sure what other files, if they were messed up, would cause a page to show twice.
If that still doesn't work, find out if cache/tpl_prosilver_index_body.html.php displays more than one html body.
That might be my last idea; I'll have to think about it a bit more.

Comment: I have tried that, even tried using phpBB from one of my sites that does work properly. And no other pages on my site show the same behaviour